# c# Is it possible to use Extensions Methods to implement Implicit conversions?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, implicit-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: implicit operator and extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685156/c-implicit-operator-and-extension-methods)

I have a common library project defining a number of types (nothing too complex, just properties mainly).  Two projects are referencing this common library: a client application and a webservice.

My intention is for the webservice to return type T, then use T in the client application.  Normally I'd have to convert the type returned by the webservice to T again (because of the proxy class, T is returned as WebService.T), but I'm hoping to use [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) instead.

As the original Common class has no knowledge of the web service proxy class, I'm wondering if I could make use of [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)  to implement the implicit conversion.  Sort of something like

```
public static implicit operator MyObject(this MyProxyObject value)
    {
        //stuff
    }
```

which the compiler doesn't like at all.

Is something like this even possible?

**Update**

Ok, first off I had the 2.0 framework referenced so that explains my compiler problems.

Secondly, I'm able to achieve the conversion by creating a method extension "ToModel" (or something).  So in terms of the business objective, I will be able to easily convert my types by calling WebService.T.ToModel().

Though I doubt this could be done using implicit conversion (or whether its worth the trouble).

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is a WCF service and not a legacy ASMX service, then you could configure the service reference on the client side to ‘reuse types in referenced assemblies’. This will result in the client-side using the types in your common library instead of auto-generating proxy classes on the client-side.

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is a legacy ASMX service. :\ But your approach be pretty sound.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for that with extension methods. You should be able to remove `this` and it should compile. Or it might make more sense to have it as an `explicit` cast.

Comment: To be clear, the implicit conversion is not being declared in class T but on, say, WebServiceManager. So the enclosing type (class that the static method is in) is not of type T but of type WebServiceManager because I don't want to perform the conversion in T's declaration (as it should have no knowledge of Webservice.T proxy class).